# changing color of my row in listview in row

Tags: java, android

I want to change my color of list view. I want to change color for rows like this. The first color should be orange, then red, then grey and then green respectively. And this goes on for each rows preserving their position respectively.

It means, for every rows:

- position = 0 --> orange
- position = 1 --> red
- position = 2 --> gery
- position = 3 --> green

and this repeats in my list view.

How I can do this?

I know how to change it for odd or even row but I can not found the logic to this.

Comment: I guess, you can use `position % 4`

Comment: yes but how I do it?

Comment: Are you want to repeat the same sequence again in the list?

Comment: I got the answer I used position/4 before that was wrong. I MUST POSITION%4

Answer (score 1):

You should check the position in the adapter's getView() method.

```
int result = position % 4;
if(result == 0){
  // set orange background
} else if(result == 1){
  // set red background
} else if(result == 2){
  // set grey background
} else{
  // set green background
}
```

Comment: you can save `position % 4` result in local variable, to reduce number of computation (and use `switch` statement if you prefer).

Comment: tnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum to match the values and you can also implement your logic to return the color name based.

See the snippet below for the example. Here, My color are based on positions 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively.

```
enum Color {
    ORANGE, GREEN, RED, GREY;

    public static String getColorForRow(int position) {
        return Color.values()[position].toString();
    }
}

public class ColorCoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Color : " + Color.getColorForRow(5));
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Color doesn't exists.");
        }
    }
}
```